# Let omnichannel users select the queue to pull cases from

Tags: omnichannel, queue-based-routing

We have agents that one day work on items on one Queue and other days on another queue.
One might argue that skills-based routing might be better but overall all the other teams use Queue based routing.
So we were trying to set up OmniChannel creating 2 users presence "Available for A" And "Available for B". However only 1 service channel can be created per object so this solution is not possible since status presence are related to service channels so we can't create 1 service channel for every queue.

How could we accomplish this? My assumption is that there is no way without custom development to achieve this requirement.